# BIND DNS Server not starting

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, centos7, bind

BIND DNS Server is not working. When I start it, I am getting the following error.

```
named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-03-05 17:20:22 UTC; 9s ago
  Process: 3897 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza bash[3897]: _default/gc-ns2.templatemaza.com/IN: file not found
Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza bash[3897]: zone templatemaza.com/IN: loaded serial 2018071600
Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza bash[3897]: zone ns3.templatemaza.com/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza bash[3897]: zone ns4.templatemaza.com/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza bash[3897]: zone ns1.templatemaza.com/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza bash[3897]: zone ns2.templatemaza.com/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza systemd[1]: named.service failed.
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Let me know if you need more detail

Comment: `Mar 05 17:20:22 templatemaza bash[3897]: _default/gc-ns2.templatemaza.com/IN: file not found` <--- I'd start by addressing the error in your logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. I have removed an invalid domain from `etc/named.conf` file and restart Bind DNS server. Now it is working

Comment: Please mark this answer as the accepted solution then. :-) I'm glad you found & fixed the issue.